# php how to split url

Tags: php, string, url

how to split this url ?

http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true

i need **example** only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use parse_url like below:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true';

$values = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.',$values['host']);

echo $host[1];

?>
```

This would work for any url that has the sub domain included (www. etc)

The PHP documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 7):

use `parse_url` 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

it returns an array with the components of the given URL

you can use `parse_str` to further split the query string 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $currentURL = "http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true";
    $urlParts = parse_url($currentURL);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($urlParts);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.example.com
    [path] => /news
    [query] => q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true
)
```