# How to get specific string from static URL

Tags: php, url, split

I trying to split my static URL and get its value in my SQL Query.

`www.mydomain.com/directory/A/37/257/file.html`

I want to put url values LIKE

```
$a="A";
$b=37;
$c=257;
```

Please help me to split the above mention url.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Does your url always only have one directory, before you want to assign the values to the variables? 2. Have you tried something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php how to split url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257243/php-how-to-split-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$params = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$a = $params[2];
$b = $params[3];
//...
```

Note this will give you the parameters as strings. You can use `intval()` to convert any integer parameters.

Comment: you have 2 syntax errors. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php and not closing the statement. As per the original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30286876/1