# Trying to get the host and port out of a url in php

Tags: php

Hi all hope this makes sense.

I am wondering if there is a way to split the following with php

so

```
$url = "http://50.7.71.219:7183/listen.mp3";
```

I then need to split it into 2 more strings so i should get a result of :

```
$ip = "http://50.7.71.219";
$port = "7183";
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Seems like here is an exact answer for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257289/5739073

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s1=explode($url,":");
$s2=explode($s1[2],"/");
$ip=$s1[0].':'.$s1[1];
$port=$s2[0];
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a built in way of doing this in PHP.  Use the `parse_url` function.  This method also returns a host of other information that could be useful, [click here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to learn more.

```
<?php

$url = "http://50.7.71.219:7183/listen.mp3";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$ip = $parsedUrl['host'];
$port = (string) $parsedUrl['port'];

echo $ip . "<br />" . $port;

?>
```